# Runtime Exception when a location is declared- Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, location

I have a separate class GPSTracker.java which returns the current latitude and longitude.

```
public class Live extends Activity implements LocationListener
{   
GPSTracker gps;
Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location oldLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
float distanceTravelled=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);
    startactivity();

}
```

startactivity:

```
public void startactivity() 
{
    gps = new GPSTracker(Live.this);

    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is: \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);    
    }
    else
    {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

}
```

Whenever I do that commented out part, it gives an exception even if I declare the location outside the startactivity() in the Live class. Otherwise it displays the correct latitude and longitude.

I want to use it to calculate distance travelled, like this:

```
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{

    oldLocation.set(newLocation);
    startactivity();
    distanceTravelled+=newLocation.distanceTo(oldLocation);
    String stringdistance= Float.toString(distanceTravelled);
    TextView distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDistance);
    distance.setText(stringdistance);
}
```

Is that logic correct?

And the onLocationChanged() does not finds the newLocation in the startactivity(). How can I do that?

But first thing is I get an exception when I use location in startactivity().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But first thing is I get an exception when I use location in startactivity().

```
    Location newLocation;

    newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
```

You are trying to execute above code, but see `newLocation` is `null` (by default value) and you are trying to use `null` instead of Object and it results in `NullPointerException`.

In order to create a new object in Java, you have to use:

```
Location newLocation = new Location("test");
```

Comment: Thanks! Code has been updated! Is that onLocationChanged() part correct? Will it give me the distance travelled?

Comment: No, same problem you are using oldLocation.set(newLocation); without object creation

Comment: I have created the object in the Class. There is no exception now, but I have not tested it if the distance is changing or not.

Comment: by default  
Location oldLocation; //by default oldLocation = null;
now you are using oldLocation.set(newLocation);
it means you are trying to use null instead of object, so it will throw NPE.

You you want to use global object i.e. oldLocation, remove Location oldLocation from onLocationChanged.

Comment: No No please refresh, I have created the objects

    Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location oldLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the longitude and latitude to a non-object. This creates a NullPointerException. You have to create the ojbect location before you use it.

Comment: Location newLocation; 
won't do?

Comment: You wrote: Location newLocation = null. So the reference of this variable is null. You have to create a new Location object like this: Location newLocation = new Location([provider])

Comment: ohh thankyou! And is that onLocationChanged() part correct? Will it give me the distance travelled?
Code updated